# Why do I get #### in the NUMBER column after format?

Tags: oracle, numbers, format, sqlplus

I have two problematic columns: `Fee` NUMBER type, `AdjFee` also NUMBER.

After

```
column Fee format a5;
select Fee ID smth
from Visit;
```

I get

```
Fee    ID   smth
####  123  klkl
####  654  rfjgr
```

Comment: What kind of data is in Fee?  How big is it?

Comment: type is NUMBER(7,2). values are 12.50 to 99.99

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can adjust the number of digits you want SQL*Plus to use to display the numeric data just as you adjust the number of characters used to display character data.  Something like

```
column fee format 999999999.99
```

will tell SQL*Plus to display up to 9 digits before the decimal point and two after the decimal point.  You can adjust that, of course, if you know your fees are going to be smaller (or larger).

Comment: Thank you very much, could you advise how can i have the column name also get truncated as i use `select`.

Comment: @kbt - Sorry, I'm not sure what you are asking.  You want to force the column names to get truncated so that they're shorter than the allowed length of the column?  That doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: I have rephrased my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284580/how-to-format-a-number-column-in-oracle

Answer (score 4):

Yes, column names can be truncated (or) changed to the name you want

From your above select statement.

If you want to truncate 'Fee' column to 'Fe'. Here is the procedure -

**col c1 heading "Fe" for a5**

col c2 heading "ID" for 999

col c3 heading "smth" for a5

select fee c1, 
ID c2,
smth c3
from visit;