# How to format a NUMBER column in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, format, numbers, sqlplus

I try to `spool` output in a nice way, so i am formatting all VARCHAR2 columns to a5.
However, my problematic columns are: `SLOTNUM` of type NUMBER(2) and `FEEADJUSTMENT` of type NUMBER(5,2).
My code is:

```
column SLOTNUM format 999;
column FEEADJUSTMENT format 999.9;
.........
column [other VARCHAR2]     format a5;
select * from allTables;
```

Result is:

```
SLOTNUM DATEV ACTUA NOTES FEEADJUSTMENT TREAT NAME                                          
------- ----- ----- ----- ------------- ----- -----                                        
     12 19-JU 19-ju Treat           2.5 12345 Flu                                              
        N-13  n-13  ment                6     Shot                                       
              00:00 succe                                                                                   
              :00   ssful                                                                                    
                    l                                                                                       

     15 20-JU 20-ju Appar           5.5 12345 Flu                                                 
        N-13  n-13  atus                6     Shot                                                         
              02:00 broke                                                                                     
              :00
```

`FEEADJUSTMENT` is taking more space than it needs. Why doesn't `format 999.9` truncate the `FEEADJUSTMENT` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's using the length of the column header, [as the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_six.htm#sthref553) says:

> A NUMBER column's width equals the width of the heading or the width
>   of the FORMAT plus one space for the sign, whichever is greater.

You can alias the column with a shorter name:

```
select slotnum as slotn, ...
```

You could also treat it as a string, but you'd still need an alias really:

```
select to_char(slotnum, 'FM9999') as slotn, ...
```

You could alias is as `slotnum`, if you preferred, and the use `format a5`, but I think that would be less clear.

I'm not sure I'd describe forcing everything to `a5` as 'nice', particularly as you have values lomger than that which ware forcing column wrapping. A matter of taste, I suppose...

Comment: Yeah, because i have too many columns... i am simply start from `a5`, then i will adjust the columns appropriately. I hope it will look nice

Answer (score 1):

Format with this:

```
column SLOTNUM format a3;
column FEEADJUSTMENT format a5;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer +1. However, this won't work, it would give #####. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284092/why-do-i-get-in-the-number-column-after-format-oracle